# Python send mail with attachment issue

Tags: python, smtplib

I have a function to send an email with an attachment, but it's not working. The function is:

```
import smtplib
from pathlib import Path
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import encoders

def send_mail(send_to, subject, text, files=None, send_from='me@company.co.uk', 
        server='mail.company.co.uk', port=25):
    
    assert isinstance(send_to, list)

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
    logger.info(msg)

    for f in files or []:
        with open(f, "rb") as fil:
            part = MIMEApplication(
                fil.read(),
                Name=basename(f)
            )
        part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(f)
        msg.attach(part)

    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server, port)
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
    smtp.close()
```

And I'm calling the function as follows:

```
                send_mail(
                    send_to = ['recipient@somewhere.co.uk'], 
                    subject = 'Something', 
                    text = 'Something',
                    files = [importfile]
                )
```

Where the value of importfile is '129279_20221030.csv'

My log entry for msg is:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============9158001163180466406=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: me@company.co.uk
To: recipient@somewhere.co.uk
Date: Fri, 17 Mar 2023 09:04:02 +0000
Subject: Something

--===============9158001163180466406==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Something
--===============9158001163180466406==--
```

But the email fails to send.

I can send an email without an attachment fine with this function.

I'm not sure about how I'm passing the files parameter. Should this be the UTC path, or the path relative to SMTP server ('mail.company.co.uk'), or relative to the where the Python script is located?

You'll notice I'm a beginner. Many thanks if you can help.

Comment: _But the email fails to send._ --> Do you get an exception? If so please [edit] your question and add the exact error message.

Comment: No, I'm not sure how to log smtplib exceptions, I will explore that

Answer (score 2):

I solve this by replacing:

```
for f in files or []:
    with open(f, "rb") as fil:
        part = MIMEApplication(
            fil.read(),
            Name=basename(f)
        )
    part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(f)
    msg.attach(part)

with:

for f in files:
    with open(f) as fil:
        part = MIMEText(fil.read())
    msg.attach(part)
```

And also using os.chdir to change directory to the directory containing the file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue. You can't use the function smtp.sendmail() and msg.as_string() when sending attachments. Replace the three last lines in the send_mail function:

```
with SMTP(SERVER, PORT) as server:
        server.login(EMAIL_USER, EMAIL_PASS)
        server.send_message(msg)
```

I hope it works for you.